# Java, check if string is JSON Using Stacks

Tags: java, json, stack

```
public class JsonValidator {

public static boolean isValidJSON(String jsonString) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (char c : jsonString.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case '{':
            stack.push(c);
            break;
        case '}':
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            Character last1 = stack.pop();
            if (last1 != '{') {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        case '[':
            stack.push(c);
            break;
        case ']':
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            Character last2 = stack.pop();
            if (last2 != '[') {
                return false;
            }
            break;

        case '\"':
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            Character last3 = stack.peek();
            if (last3 == '\"') {
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                stack.push(c);
            }

            stack.push(c);
        }

    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

assertTrue(JsonValidator.isValidJSON(""{""), "The brackets and quotes are balanced, making this a valid JSON string");

This is one of my test cases, its supposed to be valid JSON but it keeps giving me false

Comment: `["}"]"` is not a valid JSON format. Your program is running fine

Comment: assertTrue(JsonValidator.isValidJSON("\"{\""), "The brackets and quotes are balanced, making this a valid JSON string");
This is one of my test cases, its supposed to be valid JSON but it keeps giving me false

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your checker is that when you check `"{"` you are pushing characters onto the stack that are never going to be popped.  Hence, the stack is not empty.

Hint: look carefully at what is being pushed and popped when you process a string.

Also, your parser is not dealing with escapes in strings at all.  And a `{` or `}` or `[` or `]` encountered within a JSON string should be treated as regular data.